# node.js + hapi.js wait for function execution before responding

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

My code responds to a request with data from an external site – it retrieves data from the internet that gets packaged with any response.

I am a javascript beginner and am not used to asynchronous programming.  Can someone tell me if I am doing this correctly:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
var ical = require('ical');

// Set up server here:
// ...

// Get data from the web:
var ical_url = 'url_here';

function fmt_events(data){
  var eventData = {events:[]}
  // format data and push onto eventData.events
  return eventData;
}

// here is where I need feedback:
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    function events_callback(err, data) {
      var eventData = fmt_events(data);
      reply.view('index', {
        title: 'Title',
        events: eventData
      });
    }
    ical.fromURL(ical_url, {}, events_callback);
  }
});
```